# use table entries instead of subfactory

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, factory-boy

I have a FactoryBoy factory for my MyUser class, assigning a default name and a corresponding company:

```
class MyUserFactory(SQLAlchemyModelFactory):      

    class Meta:                                 
        model = MyUser                
        sqlalchemy_session = db.session   

    name = 'F.Bar'
    company = factory.SubFactory(CompanyFactory)
```

**Question:** I have a specified table of possible companies which I would like to use instead of the dummy companies from `CompanyFactory`. Is there a way to read an entry from this table to use it for `company` instead of the SubFactory?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code (see http://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html#factory.lazy_attribute) :

```
class MyFactory(SQLAlchemyFactory):
    @factory.lazy_attribute
    def company(self):
        return get_some_company_object()
```